# Phonegap Android SSL can't connect from the exported APK

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using phonegap to develop an application for Android. I bought a certificate and I set it up in my server, when I try the application signed by eclipse (debug mode), it works everywhere (simulator, phone, etc), when I use the keystore to export the APK it doesn't work in the phone.

Some idea?

Regards

PS: My certificate is from rapidSSL.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. What does your app do: WebView, HttpClient? If your test device trusts the certificate issuer (RapidSSL CA) it will work, otherwise not. And what exactly do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means that the device cannot establish a connection with the server.

Comment: What is the message you get? Any warnings in logcat? What are you using to connect (see above)? You really need to provide more details.

Comment: I discovered the error, the android device didn't recognize the certificate by rapid SSL, I had to put the intermediate certificates in the server and then was working.